# Does iOS Swift support spannable textView?

Tags: swift

I Want to Implement Scannable TextView in Swift like Readmore and ReadLess in a App, It is Possible to Implement in Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Custom create that functionality by add adding more or less texts to UITextview.

Comment: How to add custom functionality by add more or less?...@good4pc

Comment: You could build it in a UILabel by toggling the amount of allowed rows between 0(unlimited) and the amount that is the read less format for you. But because UITextView has scroll it would seem it's the wrong view to use for this...

Answer (score 0):

```
var less = true
func createTextView()
{
    let spannableTextView : UITextView = UITextView()
    spannableTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400)
    spannableTextView.text="Read less text"
    spannableTextView.tag=220
    self.view.addSubview(spannableTextView)

    let buttonSpannable : UIButton = UIButton()
    buttonSpannable.frame=CGRectMake(0, (spannableTextView.frame.size.height+spannableTextView.frame.origin.x)-20, 100, 20)
    buttonSpannable.setTitle("read more..", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonSpannable.backgroundColor=UIColor.blackColor()
    buttonSpannable.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonSpannable)
}


func buttonAction(sender : UIButton!){ if let spannableTextView = self.view.viewWithTag(220) as! UITextView!{
    if(less == true)
    {
     less = false
    spannableTextView.text="read more text"
     sender.setTitle("read less..", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
    else
    { less = true
           spannableTextView.text="read less text"
           sender.setTitle("read more..", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
sender.setTitle("read less..", forState: UIControlState.Normal)}
```

Comment: nothing show in simulator, it view blank and white.\

Comment: you havent called createTextView() , thats why!! the code is just a sample, edit it upon your requirement